# If statement condition as a variable

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to run multiple reports from a single macro.

I have a combo box in a form. It has two options: expired and expiring soon.

The expired macro finds dates that are less than today.

I am looking to make the 'expiring soon' macro find dates that are within 45 days from today.

I have this line in the beginning of my loop for expired dates:

```
For Each cell In Arr
    If cell < Now And cell <> "" Then
```

What I tried was to replace the condition with a variable and use a switch case to change the variable based on the value in the combo box.

```
condition = "cell < Now And cell <> """

For Each cell In Arr
    If condition Then
```

However, it errors out. This should be the only thing I need to change to do what I need.

I also tried:

```
condition = "cell < Now And cell <> """

For Each cell In Arr
    If Application.Evaluate(condition) Then
```

Comment: You would need to create a function with `cell` as an argument that returns a boolean from that if statement. You can't store it in a string like that.

Comment: Isn't that exactly what you need to do? I only don't know where you got those double quotes from. `Dim Condition As Boolean: Condition = cell < Now And cell <> ""`.

Comment: You can write an if/then or select case to get the same end result.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this. `condition` is a String. The If-statement simply checks the content of the variable, but the VBA runtime cannot interpret the content of the variable as *code* and execute the code.

`Application.Evaluate(condition)` also isn't an option: The `Evaluate` will be executed by Excel, not by VBA. And Excel doesn't know anything about VBA variables like `cell`).

I guess you are over-complicating your task. Simply use a nested `If` or something similar. You could for example create a small function:

```
Function CheckExpired(cell As Variant, checkType As String) As Boolean
    If isEmpty(cell) Then Exit Function
    If checkType = "Expired" Then     ' <-- Replace with your value
        CheckExpired = (cell < Now)
    Else If checkType = "Soon" Then     
        CheckExpired = (cell-45 < Now)
    End If
End Function
```

And in your main code, write

```
For Each cell In Arr
    If CheckExpired(cell, ComboBox2.Value) Then
```